# Is it possible to deposit checks into our Chase checking from another bank's ATM?

Tags: united-states, check, deposits, atm

My family uses Chase for banking.  However, after moving, we can't find a Chase bank or ATM anywhere near us.

When we have checks that we want to deposit, can we use the ATM from another bank to do that?  If so, what are some banks that let you do that?

Comment: No.  You can deposit with your phone though...

Comment: Where are there no Chase branches?  I think they have one on the moon and two on the ISS.

Comment: @PeteB. You forgot to mention the one on the [4th Circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inferno_(Dante)#Fourth_Circle_.28Greed.29).

Comment: Needless to say, if you plan to live in this new area for a while, you might consider switching banks.

Comment: You might also want to look into a credit union that is part of a co-op. That way, you can use any credit union that's apart of the same co-op. Here's some more info: https://co-opcreditunions.org/

Answer (score 12):

You need to use a proper Chase bank ATM.

If there are none in your area, you could do it with your phone:

https://www.chase.com/online/digital/mobile-deposits.html

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any banks that have agreements with other banks to allow ATM deposits of checks. You might try using [the mobile app](https://www.chase.com/online/digital/mobile-deposits.html) to deposit your checks by taking pictures.

Comment: My credit union (Direct Federal Credit Union) allows deposits from any ATM in the NYCE Shared Deposit network in Massachusetts.